# Permission denied - Scheduling Witty Pi script

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, peripherals

I am trying to create a new schedule for WittyPi (On/off scheduling of RaspberryPi). In the manual it seemed really easy (http://www.uugear.com/doc/WittyPi3_UserManual.pdf) but I fear I messed up something. I cannot change the example scripts (as stated in the manual), because when I want to save my changes I get "Error saving file. Error opening file "[/../../]": Permission denied The file on disk may now be truncated!"
I also tried to create a new file and save it to the "schedules" location. I get "Error opening file "[/.../.../...]": Permission denied the file on disk may now be truncated!"

However, I can save my Schedule file perfectly fine in eg the "Downloads" folder. So I guess there is something wrong with the permissions. Is there any way to fix it? I have no experience or knowledge of Raspberry Pi so it could be just basics (and I did not understand the answers I found in the "Search" at all..). I really want to work with the WittyPi but I am stuck totally at the start...

Thank you for helping me out!

Katharina

PS: I use a RaspberryPi 3B+ and Witty Pi 3.

Comment: What command are you using to edit the scripts? Simple fix may be to run the command to edit the files with `sudo` (so if you use `nano`, then you would run `sudo nano`) at the beginning but that may have other effects...

Comment: Oh. Excuse me for not having found out that by myself... The sudo command did the job perfectly fine. Thank you for your quick answer!

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your project!

Comment: @Katharina Please create an answer about the solution. There is nothing wrong with self answers. Then mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side after two days. That prevents your Question from being shown as an unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command "sudo" nano fixes the problem. Like this one goes around the "Permission denied" issue. Thanks @Unsigned_Arduino for the solution!